# XAMPP and Acquia Dev Desktop

Tags: configuration, installation

I installed XAMPP on my local machine to use it for Drupal. But all the navigation between all the localhost websites are really slow, no matter if it's a brand new vanilla Drupal website or if it's a commerce website, drupal 7 and/or drupal 8.

I tried everything from apache config to mysql config to windows config.

I decided to try to either re-install XAMPP or install Acquia Dev Desktop instead.

2 questions:
 if i want to re-install XAMPP, do i need to uninstall it first or will it reinstall over it just fine?
 if i want to install Acquia DEV Desktop, do i need to un-install XAMPP first?

Thanks...

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD/NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
use this url for Windows version https://github.com/pmachapman
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
when you are ready for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

> if i want to install Acquia DEV Desktop, do i need to un-install XAMPP first?

No, you can run them both at the same time by [configuring different ports in Acquia Dev Desktop](https://docs.acquia.com/dev-desktop/config/#ports). Acquia Dev Desktop will also create its own hostname, so you'll access it differently. Eg, http://othersite:8080

[image: Acquia Dev Desktop port configuration]

Comment: Thanks @reepy ...

Answer (score 1):

I have both Acquia Dev Desktop and XAMPP set up separately on my machine with Windows 10. To my knowledge they function completely independent of one another.

I would play it safe and Uninstall XAMPP and simply install Aquia DevDesktop using its Apache and MySQL. It's a great option if you are on Windows, or if you are not a dev ops ninja. There are some minor quirks along the way but it's super easy once it's set up to spin up sites, or import local sites.

Once Dev Desktop is set up and working well for Drupal 7 sites, you can set up to efficiently manage Drupal 8 sites with Composer. For that you WILL need to re-install XAMPP (or equivalent) **Not for the DevDesktop environment itself**, but simply because you will need a local instance of PHP if you want to [install Composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/) globally. The Composer installer will not recognize a php instance from your Dev Desktop installation.

You can then build Drupal 8 sites using [this template](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project) via Composer, then import the codebase to Acquia Dev Desktop via `import a local site`. That template has it's own instance of drush and drupal console. There are some quirks with Composer Drush on Aquia, in that you need to set a PATH to get your database connections as described in [this article](https://www.btmash.com/article/2015-03-24/using-dev-desktop-composer-drush/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: You're the man: very informative and yes, it does help... Thanks Tony!

Comment: No problem. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=IhWAegz8glk might help with importing a composer site to Acquia after you get dev desktop and composer installed